# how to reduce the top space between collectionviewcell and collection view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, padding

I am using collection view in my project.

there is always a tap padding comes between collection view and collection view cell.

I want to set the space between collection view cell and its collection view container.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

You can use this method to tell the collection view how much space you want between rows/columns:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
     layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,  
     minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
     return 0
}
```

Read about the method here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617705-collectionview

Make sure you have your collectionView delegate set.